# How to highlight a subgraph in the original graph in GraphX for .NET?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphx-net

I have an original graph built in `GraphArea` (WPF) and its subgraph as a list of vertices and edges. I want to highlight this subgraph on the original graph. But the method `HighlightBehaviour.SetHighlighted(DependencyObject obj, bool value)` requires passing elements of the `<DependencyObject>` type to it. Can you tell me how I can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!

```
var listE = new List<IGraphControl>();
listE.AddRange(GraphArea.EdgesList.Where(a => subGraph.Edges.Contains(a.Key)).Select(a => a.Value));

foreach (var edge in listE)
{
    HighlightBehaviour.SetHighlighted((DependencyObject)edge, true);
}

var listV = new List<IGraphControl>();
listV.AddRange(GraphArea.VertexList.Where(a => subGraph.Vertices.Contains(a.Key)).Select(a => a.Value));
foreach (var vertx in listV)
{
    HighlightBehaviour.SetHighlighted((DependencyObject)vertx, true);
}
```

Comment: It's safer with `using System.Linq;`: `foreach (var edge in listE.OfType<DependencyObject>()) { HighlightBehaviour.SetHighlighted(edge, true); }`